# Fetch on multiple tables select option with multiple values insert (joins fetch insert)

Tags: php

I have two tables for cars details, one for type of fuel and another for the cars.
The fields and table names are as follows:

```
table name: |**viaturas**| 
fields: idviatura, matricula, marca, km, idtipocomb 

**combustivel** |    
fields: idcombustivel, tipocomb.
```

What I want to do is display on a form a select option that brings the select options of matricula, and then when I submit the form, it passes to insert.php automaticly the tipocomb value of that matricula. I tried with the following codes: in

form.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","xxxx");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM viaturas 
            INNER JOIN combustivel ON viaturas.idcomb = combustivel.idcomb";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
?>
    <select name="matricula">
<?php 
while ($matricula = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):; 
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $matricula["matricula"];?>|<?php echo $matricula["tipocomb"];?>"><?php echo $matricula["matricula"];?>  
        </option>
<?php
endwhile; 
?>
```

**Edited**
and on `insert.php` I tried many types of things but never worked I need to know how to pass the value tipocomb and send it to insert PHP and have the correct syntax, so that when I submit the form, in insert PHP it $_POSTS it correctly.
the insert.php looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include('database_connection.php');
    list($matricula, $tipocomb) = explode("|", $_POST["matricula"]);
    $query = "
    INSERT INTO tabledata (matricula, tipocomb) 
    VALUES(:matricula, :tipocomb)
    ";
    $statement->bindValue(':matricula', $matricula);
    $statement->bindValue(':tipocomb', $tipocomb);
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':matricula'        =>  $matricula,
            ':tipocomb'     =>   $tipocomb,
                )
    );
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo 'done';
    }

}

?>
```

it's still not working

Comment: You can't use PHP to automatically select an option once a form as already been loaded in the browser. Need to use Javascript for that.

Comment: maybe i explained myself badly, what i want is to hide the value tipocomb, and pass it to insert php, the associated tipocomb value of the matricula choosen

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks for clarification. I got hung up on the word "autocompletes", maybe "includes" is clearer.

Comment: Ok, so hsow us all the `<form>  .... to .... </form>` html. I assume this is inside a `<form>` element

Comment: Looks like what you have works: `<option value="matricula_val|tipocomb_val">`. ...a `|` deliminated value, then [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on that in your receiving PHP file.

Comment: im not managing to do the explode correctly i tried some methods alredy available that i saw on stackoverflow but my synthax or the names weren't the correct ones

Comment: tried this: <?php>
$value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'matricula');
$exploded_value = explode('|', $value);
$value_one = $exploded_value[0];
$value_two = $exploded_value[1];
?>
and on the insert statement ':matricula'  => $value_one,
   ':matricula'  =>  $value_two,
didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In whatever PHP file that handles your form upload...

Using PHP [`list`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to capture the pipe `|` deliminated values separately:

```
list($matricula, $tipocomb) = explode("|", $_POST["matricula"]);
echo "$matricula $tipocomb";

// Given an example $_POST["matricula"] value of "car|fuel" this echos the string:
// "car fuel"
```

Alternately you can leave the result of `explode` in an array:

```
$matricula_arr = explode("|", $_POST["matricula"]);
echo "{$matricula_arr[0]} {$matricula_arr[1]}";

// Given an example $_POST["matricula"] value of "car|fuel" this also echos the string:
// "car fuel"
```

---

insert.php

```
// db  prep
// data validation

list($matricula, $tipocomb) = explode("|", $_POST["matricula"]);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tabledata (matricula, tipocomb) VALUES (:matricula, :tipocomb)');
$sth->execute(array(
  ":matricula" => $matricula,
  ":tipocomb" => $tipocomb
));
```

...or:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl (matricula, tipocomb) VALUES (?, ?)");
list($matricula, $tipocomb) = explode("|", $_POST["matricula"]);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $matricula, $tipocomb);
$stmt->execute();
```

...or:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tabledata VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $matricula, $tipocomb);
list($matricula, $tipocomb) = explode("|", $_POST["matricula"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

...or:

```
list($matricula, $tipocomb) = explode("|", $_POST["matricula"]);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tabledata (matricula, tipocomb) VALUES (:matricula, :tipocomb)');
$sth->bindValue(':matricula', $matricula);
$sth->bindValue(':tipocomb', $tipocomb);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: i tried now with a slightly different insert synthax because the form contains many other fields and i might have to keep the synthax, please if you can show me and adaptation on my insert synthax it would be very cool , thank you a lot alredy for what you provided alredy

Comment: i changed the post because i posted an answere and it was a question , sorry about that

Comment: i edited one more time, you're alredy giving precious help i would just ask if you can check it just one more time, we are close to make it right , thank you a lot